# convert date format from MM/dd/yyyy to yyyyMMdd in scala dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I am very much new to scala and help regarding date format.
I have a dataframe :

```
+-----+----------+----------+-----+                                             
| name| startDate|   endDate|price|
+-----+----------+----------+-----+
|steak|01/01/1999|01/01/2000|  150|
|steak|02/02/2000|13/01/2000|  180|
| fish|03/03/2000|12/01/2000|  100|
+-----+----------+----------+-----+
```

I need to convert the enddate column to yyyyMMdd format and need the result like below:

```
+-----+----------+----------+-----+                                             
| name| startDate|   endDate|price|
+-----+----------+----------+-----+
|steak|01/01/1999|20000101  |  150|
|steak|02/02/2000|20000113  |  180|
| fish|03/03/2000|20000112  |  100|
+-----+----------+----------+-----+
```

I have tried the below code and getting "NULL" in EndDate column

```
val result  = df.withColumn("EndDate",date_format(col("endDate"), "yyyyMMdd")).select("*").show()
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

**For Spark 2.2+**

You should convert to `DateType` for the column and change the format as below

```
df.withColumn("EndDate",
  date_format(to_date(col("endDate"),"MM/dd/yyyy"), "yyyyMMdd")
)
```

**EDIT For Spark < 2.2**
use `unix_timestamp`

```
df.withColumn("date",
  date_format(unix_timestamp(col("endDate"),"MM/dd/yyyy").cast(TimestampType), "yyyyMMdd")
)
```

The one that doesnot match the format returns `null`, As `13/01/2000` is invalid for the format `MM/dd/yyyy` which gives you `null`

Comment: i have tried the suggestion and it is saying too many arguments for method to_date: (e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)org.apache.spark.sql.Column

Comment: Can you share how did you use it ?

Comment: val result = df.select(date_format(to_date(col("enddate"),"MM/dd/yyyy"), "yyyyMMdd")).show

Comment: That looks totally fine to me, can you share the full error?  or did you import `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._`, What version of spark are you using ?